# How to build a function that will constantly emit a number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous

Is there a way to build a function, that will run in the background, and will be constantly generating a random number.

However, the rest of the code will continue to run and other bits should be able to connect to that function and fetch the random number at any time.

```
// So this runs and keeps running forever.
function emit(){
    while(true){    
        return Math.random().toFixed(4);
    }
};

// This bit is capable of tapping into the emitted data and return
// the values at any time.
function listen(){
     console.log(emit);
};
```

Is it possible to do that without using `setInterval()`?

--- EDIT ---

The purpose is to feed that into websocket.

```
wss.on('connection', () => {
    wss.clients.forEach(function(client) {
        // Maybe a bit like fetch the current result of the emitter
        // and send to the client.  
        client.send(*/ listen and stream to the client */);
    }
}
```

So the client gets a constant stream of numbers:

```
0.2344, 0.9425, 0.5385, 0.2357 ...
```

Comment: Why though?? Why would you want to generate numbers that you don't need?

Comment: have a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API

Comment: I need them :) I mean, it will be a stream of data that I can access at any time and send to a client for example.

Comment: Why not generate that if you need it?

Comment: why not just generate one each time you actually need it? Otherwise you're just wasting processing power, surely

Comment: What is the actual problem that you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: I am trying to prototype a `signal-server` using `websocket`. So I am experimenting with a simpler idea. The server keeps broadcasting just float numbers `0.1253, 0.6423, 0.6423 ...` and these are sent to a client.

Comment: Does this mean you want to simulate the server side? Simulate receiving responses from the server?

Comment: not responses, but a raw `push stream`. So the numbers are just a signal that could be coming from anything, a sensor, a radio, an online payment site. I am just trying to simplify and not worry about those but just have a constant stream of mock data.

Comment: Maybe a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) is what you want.

Comment: @symbolix sending an infinite amount of data to every client that connects won't work, as you will reach network limits very fast

Comment: @JonasWilms I am on my local network. Just prototyping. There is only one client and it is me.

Comment: Until your router does automatic service discovery or such stuff :) And even on localHost it makes little sense, generate small chunks ever n milliseconds and send that to the client.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to build a function, that will run in the background, and will be constantly generating a random number.

Yes that is possible, launch a new thread with `WebWorkers` on the browsers or `spawnProcess` on NodeJS, then run a `while(true)` loop there.

> However, the rest of the code will continue to run and other bits should be able to connect to that function and fetch the random number at any time

You could write the data to a SharedBuffer from the other thread and read it from the main process whenever you want.

---

But the real question should be:

> Does that make sense?

If you want to waste energy and processing time for no reason than this makes certainly sense. If not just generate the data if you actually need it.

Comment: There will be a real data flowing in, but I am trying to build this step by step. The emitted float numbers will be a mock data, that will be later replaced by an API back-end. I am just struggling to build a stream that is picked up by a `onconnect` websocket block and sent to a client.